# Word choice between 推舉 , 推選 , 薦舉

Tags: usage

How would one translate the 推舉 , 推選 , 薦舉?

Im pretty sure they all mean something like electing or choosing. Among the three, 推選 is probably the most colloquial and conversational basic use, while 推舉 and 薦舉 are only seen in writing/more advanced level of use.

When would you use 推舉 , 推選 , 薦舉? Please give examples in Chinese with basic English translation.

Comment: bkrs： **推舉：推举**  ：1) elect; choose
我们推举他当主席。 We've chosen him as the chairman.
2) sport press (weightlifting technique)
  **推選：推选**   to elect to choose to nominate 推选他为委员会主席 elect him (to be) chairman of the committee，人们推选他当主持人。 People elected him the host.
 **薦舉：荐举**  1)to propose (for a job) to nominate to recommend 介绍；推荐。propose sb. for an office; recommend:荐举为会员 propose sb. for membership 他被荐举为校长候选人。 He was proposed as a candidate for the headmaster. Why not add   **推荐**  ? More examples at jukuu (to reinforce idea about when to use which)。

Comment: A suggests possible reason for not including  推荐 in Q  推荐  often applies to objects (unlike 推举、推選、荐举 ) e.g.jukuu: 我向你们推荐玫瑰花瓣沙拉。Watemill Inn柜台职员推荐你们旅馆。

Comment: It could be that some words are more often used. I definitely agree that 推薦 is probably the most common one out of all of them, like a 推薦信, But it is definitely interesting to see how words I'm not familiar with are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 「推舉」,「推」means "to push ", and 「舉」 means "to raise "

- 「推舉」means to "single out and elevate someone" which means " to recommend"

In 「薦舉」,「薦」means " to recommend"

- 「薦舉」means " to elevate and recommend someone"

In「推選」, 「選」means " to choose"

- 「推選」means "to single out and choose someone" / " to nominate and elect someone"

Examples :

> 我**推舉**他為經理 ( I **recommend** him to be the manager)
>
> 我**薦舉**他為經理 ( I **recommend** him to be the manager)
>
> 眾人**推舉**之下，他成為了經理 ( After everybody **recommended** him, he became the manager)
>
> 眾人**薦舉**之下，他成為了經理 ( After everybody **recommended** him, he became the manager)
>
> 眾人**推選**他為經理 ( Everybody **recommend and choose** him to be the manager)

*「推舉」;「薦舉」;「推選」only apply to people

*「推薦」is the most common term for "to recommend", followed by「推舉」and then「薦舉」

*「推薦」apply to either people or object

Example:

向日本人**推薦**美國牛肉 ( **recommend** American beef to Japanese)

我**推薦**他為經理 ( I **recommend** him to be the manager)

*「薦舉」is more commonly written as 「舉薦」

*「選舉」(election)

Comment: For differential we can say 推举 means 'recommend (someone) for promotion' while 推荐 simply means 'recommend'.

Comment: actually 推举 means to recommend someone for a position, not necessary means to promote someone within an organization

Comment: Agreed, for a better position though, and promotion doesn't necessarily imply an organization.

Comment: OP did not ask about 推荐 （was well aware of difference with the other 3,推举、推选、荐举 ), OP asks for differentiation between 推举、推选、荐举 which may not be very significant, except that reading experience would suggest 推举 to be more common than 荐举 (accordingly IME editor has 推举 but requires separate typing for 荐 and 举) and 推选 might suggest 选 (other choices were considered).

Comment: after answer has been edited (in response to comments) comments may appear to lack justification